# Java class requires permission but its already stated in android manifest

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm making an application integrated to gcm and I'm keep getting error at this point.

```
String regid = gcm.register(Common.getSenderId());
```

Where the word "register" is covered with horizontal line in middle requesting permission `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE`

I have that permission on my android manifest file but still it keep showing horizontal line and requires permission.

I'm following this tutorial : http://www.appsrox.com/android/instachat/

This is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.heylo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.heylo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.heylo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >      
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<application
    android:name="com.example.heylo.Common"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.heylo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <provider
        android:name="com.example.heylo.DataProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.heylo.provider"
        android:exported="false" >
    </provider>

    <activity
        android:name=".Message_List"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_message__list" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest?

Comment: thanks,i have uploaded pic of my android manifest.Sorry for not uploading the coding...

Comment: @damner Buddy, this is not Flickr. Please post code, not screenshots.

Comment: Sorry for that,I have added the code now,Please take a look...